MSBuild ignores build configuration specified in the /p: key
There is a Delphi project with multiple build configurations. One of the .pas files has a conditional compilation directive that includes a specific resource file for one of the configurations.
{$IFDEF PROTECT}
{$R ProtectedForm.res}
{$ELSE}
{$R *.dfm}
{$ENFIF}

I don't have this resource file. The symbol PROTECT is defined only in the Protected configuration.
I expect that when I build my project in any configurations, others that Protected, compiler don't need this resource file. When I build a project with Rad Studio, it works fine. But when I tried to build my project using msbuild: MSBuild MyProject.dproj /t:Build /p:Configuration=Debug /m /nologo, I get this error:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\20.0\Bin\CodeGear.Delphi.Targets(402,5): error E1026: File not found: 'ProtectedForm.res' [D:\Projects\MyProject\MyProject.dproj]
After some investigations, I found that msbuild chose the Protected configuration, no matter what configuration I specified in the /p: key.


The build configuration to be used is named "config" in the dproj file. So you might get better results when you add /p:config=Debug to the msbuild call.

I've tried /p:config=Debug, and even /p:BuildConfiguration=Debug but it still not work.

Not sure if that makes a difference, but my logs all show quoted values:  /P:config="Release" ... /P:configuration="Release"

Also: There are always both parameters shown in the logs.

I tried it all, but nothing changed. I suspect, that issue is in the .dproj file

You can output the full code of the project with all imports in-lined with the /preprocess switch to MSBuild. You can search that file to see where the Configuration property is used.
